# Removing Cluster Resource Dependency: SQL Server Failover Cluster

Tags: powershell

I want to remove a disk Cluster Dependency. I wanted to remove a Cluster Disk resources from a SQL Server Engine Service and add it later into the Cluster.

The script I am using is:

```
$DiskResources = @("Cluster Disk 1,.....")
foreach($resource in $DiskResources)
{    
    Remove-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource $Resource -Provider ??????
    Write-Host "Removed Cluster Disk Resource " $resource
}
```

What is the `-Provider` parameter I should use?

The examples I saw in BOL uses IP address. I don't see IP address for the Cluster Disks.

Comment: `-Provider` is the resource on which `-Resource` is currently dependent. Are you perhaps just looking for [`Remove-ClusterResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/remove-clusterresource) instead?

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks Jessen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The script should be like:

$DiskResources = @("Cluster Disk 1,.....")
foreach($resource in $DiskResources)
{
    Remove-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource "SQL Server (xxxxx)"  -Provider $resource
    Write-Host "Removed Cluster Disk Resource " $resource
}